# Is there a way to determine which axis label a user clicks on for a plot in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I know how to use the standard method to get x/y coordinates of a plot click, but it only works within the actual data area on the plot.  Is there any way to also include the bounds outside of the data region so that I can also determine whether the axis label has been clicked? I'm using ggplot.

Answer (score 0):

I could only think of an approximate solution.

- You can track the click with `shinyjs`
- You would receive a pixle value which has to be transformed into the value on the x axis. That step has to account for the scale on the x axis, the borders of the plot, the plot size in the current session and has to be invariant concerning the resizing of the app/plot. My calculation example for that is within the following code.

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

xlim <- c(1, 3)
offset_left <- 75
offset_right <- 15

ui <- basicPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  plotOutput(outputId = "plot1", click = "plot_click"),
  p(id = "date", "The x value you clicked on the axis:"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  global <- reactiveValues(x = NULL)
  
  onclick("plot1", function(event){
    plot_width <- session$clientData$output_plot1_width
    global$x <- xlim[1] + (xlim[2] - xlim[1])/0.926*(event$pageX - offset_left) / 
      (plot_width - offset_left - offset_right) - 0.08
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg, xlim = xlim)
  })

  output$info <- renderText({
    global$x
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it, but I think the resizing of the app/plot will be an issue that I can't get around.

Comment: it should work with resizing as well, no?

Comment: From your example I get different x values if the window is resized.